# WPF - Failed to resolve assembly

Tags: .net, wpf, reference, migration, .net-assembly

Currently I'm trying to resolve an issue with assembly, which is imported from my own custom package and this error causes displaying black window (Which is displayed correctly in the Visualizer inside of the Rider/VS)

Here are errors under correctly displayed component inside visualizer:
[image]

But very strange thing is **.g.** divider which causes that assembly .resources cannot be found.

My assemblies imported from personal package:
[image]

Please do you know what could cause this issue ?

I tried to delete bin/obj folder. Check my personal package, but nothing strange happens there. Also folder with Resources is generated properly in bin folder.

Comment: Do you have a misspelling error? The error message above contains `KIT.Windows.WPF.Application.CommonCore.resources`, but your picture below contains `KIT.Windows.WPF.Application.CommonCore.g.resources` with a `g` between `CommonCore` and `resources`.

Comment: Thanks for replay. but no, it's generated by default, but I not able to find why.